# Extract values inside parenthesis from MySQL INSERT query string

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli

We have been given thousands of MySQL INSERT query strings like this:

```
$sql = INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( 123, '456', 'Don't fail', 'hellow world' )
```

The sql strings were just given to us in a project.

The issue is that, in some queries, some field values have single quotation marks in the middle so when running `mysqli_query($sql)`, it throws an error.

In my example, if I escape the whole $sql string, it will also escape \'456\' or \'Don\'t fail\', and that will also throw and error, that is why I need to extract and escape the values individually and then put the sql query back together.

I need to extract the values from inside the parenthesis and get them in an array, so I can escape them individually. 
Something like this:

```
$vals[0] = 123
$vals[0] = 456
$vals[0] = Don't fail
$vals[0] = hellow world
```

Is there a regex I can use?

I know the number of columns of table "my_table".

Is there even any other solution?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to escape them? How are they even generated? Is this inside of SQL file? What does cakePHP has to do with this? or MySQLi?

Comment: The sql strings were just given to us in a project. In my example, if I escape the whole $sql string, it will also escape \'456\' or \'Don\'t fail\', and that will also throw and error, that is why I need to extract and escape the values individually and then put the sql query back together.

Comment: No I meant where did you get the SQL in such format? I assume it wasn't given to you by a genie. If it came from mysqldump or from phpMyAdmin it would've been already escaped. If it was written manually by someone then a question is why?

Comment: What happens is that we have a huge sql dump file with 750+ tables and millions of rows, when I import it into phpmyadmin, it times out. So I managed to partition into 750 smaller .sql dumps (one for each table) using file_get_contents on the original huge dump. Maybe that is why they came out un-escaped? Please help me

Comment: ^^ HOW did you partition them? Did you compare the original and the result? Is the problem in original too?

Comment: I cant open the original because it is to large. The only way I can see contents is using file_get_contents and that is what I get.

Comment: How are you trying to open it then? There are IDEs which should handle even very large files.

Comment: @Alex How would `mysqli_real_escape_string` help on a full SQL query?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Ast9A7/1 risky, but might help

Comment: @tim looks great! but what would be the php snippet? Can you please make it an answer?

Comment: @Dharman What happens is that we have a huge sql dump file with 750+ tables and millions of rows, when I import it into phpmyadmin, it times out. So I managed to partition into 750 smaller .sql dumps (one for each table) using file_get_contents on the original huge dump. Maybe that is why they came out un-escaped? How can I use IDE instead?

Comment: The SQL queries you got are incorrect. I'd ask supplier to fix them instead of trying to repair it.

Comment: The escaping must be done for _each_ value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to escape the apostrophes, you could create a pattern that matches the entire SQL string and capture each of the values.

```
$pattern = "/(?:[ \w]+ \() (\d+), '(\d+)', '(.+?)', '(.+?)' \)/";
```

Then bind those values as parameters to a prepared statement for each of the insert statements.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

foreach ($inserts as $insert) {
    preg_match($pattern, $insert, $matches);
    list ($full, $a, $b, $c, $d) = $matches;
    $stmt->bindValue("isss", $a, $b, $c, $d);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: What about if other INSERT queries for other tables have different pattern and amount of columns, ie, ( '123', 'abce', 123, 'what's up', 1, 'nice' ). Is there a way to make the pattern more generic?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking it was all the same insert. Yeah, probably so, but I'm away from the computer at the moment. I'll take another look when I get back

Answer (score 0):

you want to be really careful you don't get unexpected results here,

```
<?php

$re = '/\b\'\b/';  // b for word boudry

$str = <<<EOT
$sql = INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( 123, '456', 'Don't fail', 'hellow world' )
EOT;

$subst = '\\\\\'';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

won't work if you start or end with a double apostrophe, IE:  `$sql = INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( 123, '456', 'Don't fail', 'hellow worlds'' )`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ast9A7/1

Comment: There is enough situations where the apostrophe is at the end of the word so the regex fail (it will not be escaped).

Comment: @tim this is great!! It is scaping 99.9999% of all strings. However, it is not escaping this one: `VALUES (13318,'In 'Campus Confidential,' a Professor Laments That Teaching Is Not the Priority of Teachers','https://www.nytimes.com/','1510604711.html',1510604491)` why?

Comment: @tim it is not escaping this string value: `In 'Campus Confidential,' a Professor Laments That Teaching Is Not the Priority of Teachers`

Comment: told you it was not going to be perfect, you need to tweak to your specific needs